# Flexslider In Magento: Works on homepage, not on category page

Tags: jquery, magento, flexslider

I am using flexslider on the homepage for the banner as well as the testimonials bit on the footer.
You may check both working here: http://propshop24.in/new/index.php

But, strangely, the testimonials slider is not working on the category page. You can check it here: http://propshop24.in/new/index.php/bar-party.html

It keeps giving me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I tried using noConflict() as well but to no use.

I'm sure this is a small glitch. What am I missing? Any idea how do I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `skin/frontend/default/propshopjm/js/init.js`.
The contents of that file are:

```
var jjm = jQuery.noConflict();
jjm(document).ready(function() {
    jjm(".searchonoff").click(function(){
        jjm(".searchpop").fadeToggle("open");
    });
    $('.testislider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        easing: "swing",
        animationLoop: true,
        slideshow: true,
        slideshowSpeed: 5000,
        animationSpeed: 400,
        controlNav: false,
        directionNav: true
    });
/* $('.testislider').bxSlider(); */
});
```

replace the line `$('.testislider').flexslider({` with `jQuery('.testislider').flexslider({`